# relationship between distance and isomorphic graph

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory, is there any relationship between distance d_G(u,v) (shortest length of any two vertices u and v in graph G) and isomorphic graph?

If there exist two connected graphs G and H and a 1-to-1 function 'f' from V(G) onto V(H) (V(G) means set of vertices in G) such that d_G(u,v) = d_H(f(u),f(v)) for every two vertices u and v of G. Are G and H isomorphic?

If there exist two connected graphs G and H and a 1-to-1 function 'f' from V(G) onto V(H) (V(G) means set of vertices in G) such that d_G(u,v) ≠ d_H(f(u),f(v)) for every two vertices u and v of G. Are G and H not isomorphic?

Comment: Hint: check u,v where d_G(u,v)=1.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the definition of an isomorphism of graphs in graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism), any two vertices u and v of G should be adjacent in G if and only if ƒ(u) and ƒ(v) are adjacent in H.

1. By the way, if d(u, v)=1, u and v are adjacent. From assumption, if d(u, v)=1, d(f(u), f(v))=1, so if u and v are adjacent, f(u) and f(v) are adjacent. Therefore, the given 1-to-1 function f is the isomorphism of the graph.
2. The contraposition of the problem is "If G, H are isomorphic, there's no f such that for any two vertices u and v, d(u, v) ≠ d(f(u), f(v))". However, f exists.

[Obviously, two graphs are isomorphic but](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMnr5.png)

```
d(u_1, u_2) = 1
d(u_1, u_3) = 2
d(u_1, u_4) = 3
d(u_2, u_3) = 1
d(u_2, u_4) = 2
d(u_3, u_4) = 1

d(f(u_1), f(u_2)) = 2
d(f(u_1), f(u_3)) = 1
d(f(u_1), f(u_4)) = 1
d(f(u_2), f(u_3)) = 3
d(f(u_2), f(u_4)) = 1
d(f(u_3), f(u_4)) = 2
```